# Equations of lines in 3 dimensions with vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, vectors

The intersection of the planes defined by
$$v• \begin{pmatrix} 8 \\ 1 \\ -12 \end{pmatrix} = 35$$
and
$$v• \begin{pmatrix} 6 \\ 7 \\ -9 \end{pmatrix} = 70$$
is a line. Find an equation of this line.

I have taken the dot products like so

$$\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}• \begin{pmatrix} 8 \\ 1 \\ -12 \end{pmatrix} = 8x+1y-12z = 35$$

$$\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}• \begin{pmatrix} 6 \\ 7 \\ -9 \end{pmatrix} = 6x+y-9z=70$$

But now have no idea on where to go! I thought about using systems of equations, but there are three variables and two equations! Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Even if it's terrible, you have to prove that you have tried something or chances are your problem will get deleted. You are much more likely to find someone willing to tell you what you are doing wrong than someone who will just do your homework for you.

Comment: Will do! Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your equation set is given by

\begin{align}
8v_{1} + v_{2} - 12v_{3} &= 35 \\
6v_{1} + 7v_{2} - 9v_{3} &= 70
\end{align}

As you stated, you have less equations than variables, *so we set one of the variables to be a parameter*. Setting $z = t$, we get

\begin{align}
8v_{1} + v_{2} &= 35 + 12t \\
6v_{1} + 7v_{2} &= 70 + 9t
\end{align}

Solving this last system yields

\begin{align}
v_{1} &= \frac{7 + 3t}{2} \\
v_{2} &= 7
\end{align}

Hence the equation of the line is given by

\begin{align}
\vec{v} &= \left( \frac{7 + 3t}{2}, 7, t \right) \\
&= \left( \frac{7}{2}, 7, 0 \right) + t \left( \frac{3}{2}, 0, 1 \right)
\end{align}